# Android FFMPEG: images to mp4 video converting

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have tried many possible command line options with ffmpeg, however not getting this to work. Heres is my command file generator method :

```
 private String[] generateCommandFile() {
    ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<>();

    cmd.add("-y");
    cmd.add("-f");
    cmd.add("concat");
    cmd.add("-safe");
    cmd.add("0");
    cmd.add("-i");
    String picturesTextFile = generateMergingFilesTexts();
    if (picturesTextFile == null) {
        return null;
    }
    cmd.add(picturesTextFile);
    cmd.add("-i");
    String audioTextFile;
    if (numberOfAudioFiles > 1) {
        audioTextFile = generateAudioFilesTexts();
    } else {
        audioTextFile = getAudioFilePath(audioRecordingFileName + Integer.toString(1));
    }

    cmd.add(audioTextFile);

    cmd.add("-vsync");
    cmd.add("vfr");
    cmd.add("-pix_fmt");
    cmd.add("yuv420p");

    String currentDateTimeString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.US).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    File dirOut = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "D:T:" + currentDateTimeString);
    if (!dirOut.exists()) {
        dirOut.mkdirs();
    }
    directoryPath = dirOut.getAbsolutePath();
    File fileOut = new File(dirOut, "T__" + Long.toString(totalTime) + "__P__" + Integer.toString(picturesModelInfo.getNumberOfShots()) + ".mp4");
    cmd.add(fileOut.getAbsolutePath());
    Log.d(TAG, "Saving File At " + fileOut.getAbsolutePath());

    String[] finalCommand = new String[cmd.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < cmd.size(); i++) {
        finalCommand[i] = cmd.get(i);
    }

    String finalString = "";
    for (String command : finalCommand) {
        finalString += command;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Final Command Is " + finalString);
    return finalCommand;
}
```

and here is my Final Command

```
-y-fconcat-safe0-i/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.essentialsln.memtalk/files/pictures_merging.txt-i/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.essentialsln.memtalk/files/AudioRecording1.3gp-vsyncvfr-pix_fmtyuv420p/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.essentialsln.memtalk/files/D:T:19 July 2017/T__2__P__3.mp4
```

The main problem is that video not playing in android default player - displays ("Cannot Play video, unsupported file type"), but it works with VLC program. ))

Anu Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Your final command has no spaces in it, and you need to show the complete console output/log from this command. Why are you using the concat demuxer for image input? It would be easier to use the image demuxer instead (unless you're trying to vary the image display durations). I would give you an example but I don't know the file names of the image inputs. Do all of the image inputs have the same width, height, and pixel format? If you don't know the answer to this question then show info for each image: `ffmpeg -i image1 -i image2 -i image3`, etc.

Comment: i am using this library , so i think i can use it without compile 

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: ffmpeg works  perfect at my side, one problem is that i cannot open it with default android player ), maybe i have missed something in my command strings .

Comment: I'll ask again: please show the complete console output/log from the `ffmpeg` command. You still did not answer my questions in my first comment. Why do you make it hard to provide help?

Comment: I have printed Metadata for you, is it usefull info? 

`Metadata:
major_brand     : 3gp4
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: isom3gp4
creation_time   : 2017-07-20 09:25:40 com.android.version: 6.0
Duration: 00:00:02.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 168 kb/s
Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 156 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time   : 2017-07-20 09:25:40
handler_name    : SoundHandle
metadata.txt: Read-only file system`

Comment: Also this 

`Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
 Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.essentialsln.memtalk/files/AudioRecording1.3gp'`

Comment: I need the **complete** output. Please [edit] your question to add this info instead of trying to fit it into the limited space of comments.